# Can't run python3 in command line

Tags: python, python-3.11

I have installed python 3.11 on my Widnows from its official website, and when I want to run it in command line by typing "python3" it doesn't run Python for me; Instead it opens Microsoft store for me to download Python!

I tried reinstalling it but it didn't fix. Did I miss anything before installing or in the installation process?

Comment: You sure add it in your path in windows?

Comment: If you have installed python successfully, press the windows key and search for idle. Open this app, thats the default python ide

Comment: Try `python` instead of `python3`.

Comment: @Jibel Thanks friend. That was the problem I guess. I forgot to add it to the path when I was installing it. reinstalled it and checked the box asking to add it to path and now I can easily run it in the command line. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are sure you installed the python you just need to [add your python to your windows path](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/#:%7E:text=Type%20%E2%80%9CPython%E2%80%9D%20in%20the%20Windows,then%20select%20%E2%80%9COpen%20file%20location%E2%80%9C), then windows would know where is the python